# XML validation using Apache Xerces - Java

Tags: java, xsd, xml-validation, xerces

I'm trying to validate XML using external XSD in java. But the examples I have seen are adding dependency of Xerces but importing SchemaFactory , etc from javax.xml

Why this is so ? How to validate Xml using Xerces in java ?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need an external dependency to Xerces. The JVM contains its own Xerces version. But the internal version's package structure differs from external Xerces.

Internal package is: `com.sun.org.apachge.xerces`.

External package is: `org.apache.xerces`.

`java.xml` is only an abstraction layer to the implementing classes provided e.g. by Xerces.

The default implementation is the internal Xerces version. But if you include the external Xerces Jars, there is a mechanism to use the external implementation automatically.

E.g. look inside xercesImpl.jar (I downloaded the binary distribution of Xerces 2.12.2). Under `META-INF/services` there are some text files like `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory`.

The content of `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory` is:

```
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory
```

So at runtime, if xercesImpl.jar is on the classpath you get this class as the implementation for SchemaFactory.

The underlying mechanism is documented in class [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).